# setting textfield constraints to hold effective in screen sizes 4.5 in to 6.5 in

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

if I set **fixed width** it either appears too large for small screen (4.5 in) or too small for large screen (6.5 in)

and

> is there any special way to ensure the constraints hold good in all
>   constraints

Comment: you can use leading and trailing constrain instead of fixed width

Comment: I have tried that, the issue is in larger screen leading will hold good, but trailing will not hold up i.e if I set 20 - leading and trailing it will end up as 20 leading and 50 trailing...

Comment: add constrain equal width with super view and change multiplier form 1 to as you want for ex 70 % of super view use multiplayer 0.7

Comment: so the best way to handle it is as suggested enforcing PROPORTIONAL constraints and font to auto-shrink does the best service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Jatin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4665854/jatin-kathrotiya) mentioned in the comments, you can use **leading** and **trailing** anchors relative to the view like this,

```
textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

Or, you could set the **width** as a multiplier to the width of the view.

```
textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.80).isActive = true
```

**Note:** Change the constant and multiplier values to suit your needs.

Comment: yes, setting the text field width relative to super view width work effectively for all screens

Comment: @pandu keep in mind that you would need to specify one more horizontal anchor along with the width anchor to align it properly. and there is an extra parameter - constant which will help you adjust the width you get after applying the multiplier.